# First row of table is not showing in drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am displaying email in drop-down list, but it did not show first email of table in the drop-down list, following is my code, please check:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query= mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM register");
$options="";
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $options.= '<option '.(($row[0]==$email)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
}
?>
<select name="email" id="email">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">SELECT EMAIL</option>
    <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fetch the first row before the loop (even if you don't use the result), so when the loop starts, it will start at the second record, as the pointer was moved there after the first `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` call.

Simply remove `$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);`.

```
$options = "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Comment: Thank you @Qirel :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove : `$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` it is removing your 1st record

Comment: Thank you @Ashu :)